# When using Apache Httpclient , is there a way to get downloading status?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

Anyway to get he downloading status like how much it has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends™: the server can (or not) send a Content-Length header before it sends the content itseft. In this case, yes, it's possible: get the header value, then get the response output steam and read from it by chunks of fixed size, and update the status at each iteration.
If the header is not present, no, you have no clue about the remaining content to read.